# How to convert a string of numbers in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, numbers

`a = ["5.0", 2.25, 3.0, "4.0"]` how to get `a = [5.0, 2.25, 3.0, 4.0].`

I can able to get `a = [5, 2.25, 3, 4].` but i need like this `[5.0, 2.25, 3.0, 4.0]`

can any one help me. please,

Thanks

Comment: In JS (unlike other languages) there is no difference between `5` and `5.0` they're both just _numbers_

Comment: There's no such a number in JS.

Comment: Ah, now I see. See @Teemu and George's comment then

Answer (score 2):

Well simply map the result of `Number`:

```js
var a = ["5.0", "2.25", "3.0", "4.0"];

var b = a.map(Number);
console.log(b);
```

**Note:**

You can't preserve the `0` from `5.0` in a `Number`, it won't be a valid number.

You can use `.toFixed(1)`to preserve it, but the results will be strings:

```
var b = a.map(function(v){
    return Number(v).toFixed(1);
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var a = ["5.0", "2.25", "3.0", "4.0"];

var b = a.map(function(v){
    return Number(v).toFixed(1);
});
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Thanks fot your effort @chsdk Actualy by using toFixed(1), and i pushed it in array. then I got  ["5.0", 2.25, "3.0", 4.0] like this. but now i want to remove it and try to get [5.0, 2.25, 3.0, 4.0]

Comment: I know there is no diff 5, and 5.0. but my compare is not matching so i need 5.0. with out  " ". :(

Comment: You can't just get `5.0`, a number will be always stored without this `0` in JavaScript, so it won't be possible to achieve it without wrapping it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Map the values with a parsing call:

```js
var a = ["5.0", 2.25, 3.0, "4.0"];
var b = a.map(function(c) {
  return parseFloat(c.toString());
});
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

All numbers in JavaScript are floating point numbers, but when there is no decimal component, the runtime doesn't bother showing the decimal because, for example, `5.0` is exactly the same value as `5`.

If you really want to see the numbers with this decimal, you can convert them back to strings (for display) and control the precision with the **[`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)** method, which operates on a number, but returns a string:

```js
var a = ["5.0", 2.25, 3.0, "4.0"];

var b = a.map(Number);

b.forEach(function(num){
  console.log(num.toFixed(2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = ["5.0", 2.25, 3.0, "4.0"];

a.map(function(b){
    return parseFloat(b).toFixed(1)
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Note that this will drop decimals of the more accurate numbers to one as well ...

Answer (score 0):

Basically Javascript does not return any value after decimal point if value is 0. You need to do it with programatically.

You can parse string with parseFloat and then you can use this function `.toFixed()` or `.toString()` so that it will give numbers with decimal point, even if 0 after decimal point.